# What permission of DBUS-Daemon Helper? Own daemon

Tags: dbus

I have tried to create my trace dbus daemon, needed to kio terminal autospawning routines. Problem is, I have got:

```
method call time=1666778936.233014 sender=:1.1 -> destination=org.kde.kio.appkinddetector.system_helper serial=2 path=/org/kde/framework/kio/console_systemdaemon; interface=org.kde.framework.kio.console_systemdaemon.mobj; member=registerProcess
uint32 32765
error time=1666778936.270515 sender=org.freedesktop.DBus -> destination=:1.1 error_name=org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.PermissionsInvalid reply_serial=2
string "The permission of the setuid helper is not correct"
```

Config files are:

```
# cat /etc/dbus-1/system.d/org.kde.kio.appkinddetector.system_helper.conf
<!DOCTYPE busconfig PUBLIC 
"-//freedesktop//DTD D-BUS Bus Configuration 1.0//EN"
"http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/dbus/1.0/busconfig.dtd">
<busconfig>
 
<policy user="root">
  <allow own="org.kde.kio.appkinddetector.system_helper"/>
</policy>

<policy context="default">
  <allow send_destination="org.kde.kio.appkinddetector.system_helper"
send_interface="org.kde.framework.kio.console_systemdaemon.mobj"/>
</policy>

</busconfig>

# cat /usr/share/dbus-1/system-services /org.kde.kio.appkinddetector.system_helper.service
[D-BUS Service]
Name=org.kde.kio.appkinddetector.system_helper
Exec=/kde/src/build/franework/kio/bin/kio-appkinddetector-systemservice
User=root
```

I think, there exist an configuration error, but I cannot figure out, where.
I work inside docker daemon, which OpenSUSE Tumbleweed installed. I also give high access/permission of host to container.

Comment: I tried to change permissions of /usr/libexec/dbus-1/dbus-daemon-launch-helper. I also move (backup) and restore after testing /etc/dbus-1/system.conf file, because there was no user tag.

Comment: Did you solved this issue ?